# Gradle projects sharing artifactory plugin dependency

Tags: java, gradle, artifactory

I have three gradle projects: 'foo', 'bar' and 'core'. 'foo' and 'bar' need to use the artifactory plugin: 'foo' publishes dependencies needed by 'bar'. The artifactory plugin dependency is defined in 'core' and I need project 'foo' and 'bar' to be able to use it.

Is there a clear way of doing this in gradle 2.12? Project 'core' needs to exist because if the version of the dependencies 'foo' publishes changes I want to update 'core' instead of 'bar', hence avoiding a redeploy of 'bar'

Project foo - build.gradle:

```
group 'foo'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply from: "/path/to/core/artifactory-war.gradle"

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
```

Project bar - build.gradle:

```
 group 'foo'
    version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    apply from: "/path/to/core/artifactory.gradle"

    apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
```

Project core - artifactory-war.gradle:

```
apply from: "/path/to/core/artifactory.gradle"

apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

publishing {
    //...
}
```

Project core - artifactory.gradle:

```
group 'core'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.4.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin

artifactory {
    // ...
}
```

As of now I cannot use the artifactory plugin in project 'foo':

```
Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Gradle 3.0, this is possible using the [improved plugin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/3.0/release-notes#improved-plugins-dsl). The example from the documentations looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'my.special.plugin' version '1.0' apply false
}

subprojects {
    if (someCondition) {
        apply plugin 'my.special.plugin'
    }
}
```

Therefore your case should be:

**core**

```
plugins {
  id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.4.0"
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin "com.jfrog.artifactory"
}
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing it without Foo and Bar being a subprojects of gradle-core? Or is that not a valid gradle use case?

Comment: It might be valid, but there might be a better way :) I think that this line: `apply plugin: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin` might actually do something that is not available in `foo`. Does it work if you include` artifactory.gradle` instead of `artifactory-war.gradle`? There might be something else breaking it.